# How long does an erase message sent from Android Device Manager last; when can I turn it back on?

Tags: settings, google, android-device-manager

I lost my phone recently and sent an erase message from Android Device Manager. I got my phone back and, because the battery was flat, it hadn't gone through. I had cancelled phone and had no WiFi, so I went into Google Settings and turned Android Device Manager off. Connected to internet without it being wiped. Is it safe to turn Android Device Manager back on without worrying that the original intent to wipe the phone will continue? How long do I have to wait to turn it back on?